# How to drag layers in sync

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a layer and several child layer to this main layer. I can drag each child layer separately using ccTouchMoved method. I need to drag the main layer so the other layers will follow, but how Can I drag the main layer through the ccTouchMoved?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the main layer in the same way you can drag the child layers

Either, you can have a child layer accept the ccTouchMoved and then have that layer send a message to the parent. `parent.position = CGPointMake(x, y)` in example

Or, you can have the child layers ignore the ccTouchMoved event until it's propagated to the main layer (which obviously has to be touch enabled for this to work)